# php/mysql compare arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

My question:
I got a phpmyadmin database ( and using php 5),
with 2 tables to compare a football toto tournament.
the strings that i must compaire are like the following :

```
1|2|3|1|1|2|3|1|2|3|3
```

( in total 43 numbers) i know that i must use explode for taking out the "|" between them (because its saved as a string)
but the final score is also saved like that. so i must compare all (guessed outcomes from matches with the final score string. how do it do it so that i can see who has got the most guessed right?

And that it would be shown as 1e place, 2e place, 3e place and so on?

Would be a great help,
sorry if i lack at something.

Comment: I can't understand what is algorithm for places, but it can be useful: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain that I understand the question correctly, but if the two arrays are of the same length, you can use the same iterator for both of them.

After you've explode()d the strings into arrays:

```
$one = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$two = array(8, 2, 3, 6, 1);

$results = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($one); $i++) {
    $results[$i] = $one[$i] - $two[$i];
}
```

Note that the above code is untested, and instead of whatever calculation you use, I just subtract the value of each $two element from each $one element.

Hope it helps.

Comment: well i can explain it better for you to understand what i must do with multiply arrays.

For instand:

1|2|1|3|1|2|3 and so on.. i want to filter out the " | " sings of the string from the database (i want to use explode to achiev that)
<-- is the score somebody thinks it will be
the score how ever is this:
2|2|1|2|2|1|1 <--- now both strings are saved in the database.

know i want to compair what a user has guessed and what the real score is:

guess: 1|2|1|3|1|2|3
real:  2|2|1|2|2|1|1

so the user guessed 2 scores correct, now i want to know how this can be shown as just a score of 2.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand the question well...

```
$guess = array(1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3);
$real = array(2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1);
$score = 0;
$length = count($real);

for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  if($guess[$i] == $real[$i])
    ++$score;
}

echo $score;
```